# SQL Group, get First purchase, Last Purchase and last employee associated with last purchase

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In my DB I have Customers, who make Purchases, and those purchases are then associated with an employee who assisted with that purchase. I have written a query below that will provide me with a list of customers with how many total purchases they have made, their first purchase and the last purchase. I also want the employee name associated with the last purchase?

```
Customer
-cstId
-cstName

Purchase
-cstId
-soldDate
-empId

Employee
-FirstName
-LastName
-empId


SELECT customer.cstName, MAX(purchase.soldDate) AS [Last Purchase], MIN(purchase.soldDate) AS [First Purhcase], COUNT(invTruck.invId)
               AS [Total Purchases]
FROM  customer INNER JOIN
               purchase ON customer.cstId = purchase.cstId 
               INNER JOIN
               employee ON purchase.empId = employee.empId
GROUP BY customer.cstName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use a stored procedure?  I usually fall back to memory tables for situations like this.

```
Declare @tblCust TABLE (
    cstid int null,
    cstName varchar(50) null, 
    lastpurchase datetime null,
    firstpurchase datetime null, 
    empid varchar(50) null
    )
Insert into @tblCust(cstid, cstname, lastpurchase, firstpurchase)        
SELECT purchase.cstid, customer.cstName, MAX(purchase.soldDate) AS [Last Purchase], 
    MIN(purchase.soldDate) AS [First Purhcase]
FROM  customer INNER JOIN
    purchase ON customer.cstId = purchase.cstId 
GROUP BY purchase.cstId, customer.cstName

Update t set EmpId = p.EmpId
From @tblCust t
        INNER JOIN Purchase p ON t.cstId = p.cstid and t.LastPurchase = p.soldDate
```

You now have the employee id on a temp table that you can return your data from, or join to any other tables you may need.

Answer (score 0):

you could use APPLY: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx

use cross apply to get the list of purchases and the respective employee, with TOP 1 and sort by soldDate desc

example:

```
CROSS APPLY (
select top 1 p.empId
from purchase p
where p.cstId = customer.cstId
order by soldDate desc
) o (emp)
```

and add o.emp to your select

i'm not 100% sure that the syntax is 100% perfect but the idea is there :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have some primary key on purchase table.  I named it "purchaseID":

```
SELECT customer.cstName, 
    MAX(purchase.soldDate) AS [Last Purchase], 
    MIN(purchase.soldDate) AS [First Purhcase], 
    COUNT(invTruck.invId)  AS [Total Purchases], 
    LastPurchase.empID     AS [Last Purchase Employee]
FROM  customer INNER JOIN
           purchase ON customer.cstId = purchase.cstId 
           INNER JOIN
           employee ON purchase.empId = employee.empId
           CROSS APPLY (
               SELECT TOP 1 * 
               FROM purchase px 
               WHERE px.purchaseID = purchase.purchaseID 
               ORDER BY px.soldDate DESC) AS LastPurchase
GROUP BY customer.cstName,
    LastPurchase.empID
```

What the CROSS APPLY does is runs the enclosed select statement on every record, utilizing the WHERE criteria also inside.  It behaves similarly to an INNER JOIN relative to an OUTER APPLY which behaves similarly a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

You can just extend it with a simple SCALAR SUBQUERY

```
SELECT
    customer.cstName,
    MAX(purchase.soldDate) AS [Last Purchase],
    MIN(purchase.soldDate) AS [First Purhcase],
    COUNT(invTruck.invId) AS [Total Purchases],
    (SELECT TOP(1) e.lastname
     FROM purchase p
     INNER JOIN employee e ON p.empId = e.empId
     WHERE customer.cstId = p.cstId
     ORDER BY p.soldDate DESC) lastPurchaseEmployee
FROM  customer
INNER JOIN purchase
    ON customer.cstId = purchase.cstId 
INNER JOIN employee
    ON purchase.empId = employee.empId
GROUP BY
    customer.cstId, customer.cstName
```